# Write a program which gets a number from a user and identify whether it is an Integer or a Float in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying this :

print " Enter Value "
num = gets.chomp

## also tried .kind_of? but didn't work

if num.is_a? Float
print " Number is in float "

## also tried .kind_of? but didn't work

else num.is_a? Integer
print " Number is in integer "

end

Comment: This doesn't seem related to Rails, maybe remove that tag?

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has not been maintained in years and has open, unpatched security vulnerabilities? You should update as soon as possible!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is that `gets` returns a `String` you can actually determine this based on the fact that you are chaining `String#chomp`, which removes the trailing "separator" which by default is return characters (newlines) e.g.

```
num = gets.chomp # User enters 1 
#=> "1"
```

In order to turn this `String` into a Numeric you could explicitly cast it via `to_i` or `to_f` however you are trying to determine which one it is.

Given this requirement I would recommend the usage of `Kernel#Integer` and `Kernel#Float` as these methods are strict about how they handle this conversion. knowing this we can change your code to

```
print " Enter Value " 
num = gets.chomp
if Integer(num, exception: false) 
  puts "#{num} is an Integer"
elsif Float(num, exception: false) 
  puts "#{num} is a Float" 
else 
  puts "#{num} is neither an Integer or a Float"
end
```

**Note:** the use of `exception: false` causes these methods to return `nil` if the `String` cannot be converted to the desired object, without it both methods will raise an `ArgumentError`. Additionally when I say these methods are strict about conversion a simple example would be `Integer("1.0") #=> ArgumentError` because while `1 == 1.0`, `1.0` itself is a `Float` and thus not an `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

```
num = 6.6
num.is_a?(Integer)
=> false
num.is_a?(Float)
=> true
```

```
num = 6
num.is_a?(Integer)
=> true
num.is_a?(Float)
=> false
```

Minor note, `#print` is not the correct method to print to the screen. The correct method is `#puts`.
So your code would look like this:

```
if num.is_a?(Float)
  puts 'Number is a float.'
elsif num.is_a?(Integer)
  puts 'Number is an integer.'
else
  puts 'Number is neither a float nor an integer.'
end
```

I suspect `#gets` returns a string though, which means you'll need to convert from a string into a numeric first.

Comment: As of ruby 2.4 `Fixnum` and `Bignum` were deprecated [See Notes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/) and the class returned is `Integer`

Comment: I'm using an older version of Ruby for sure. Thanks for the reality check. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @engineersmnky: They were *always* internal implementation details. The only class that was guaranteed to exist was `Integer`, even long before Ruby 2.4. For example, even the ISO Ruby Language Specification, which was written 8 years before Ruby 2.4, already is very clear that `Integer` *may* have implementation-specific subclasses, but does not *have* to. And it does not restrict either the number or the names of the subclasses, so there could be just one or three or more and they don't have to called `Fixnum` and `Bignum`. Using those classes has *always* been a bug, for at least the 20 …

Comment: … years that I have been following Ruby.

Comment: It is understandable that these subclasses would be used (abused?) though, as `1.class` clearly returns `Fixnum` in a Ruby 2.3 console...

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you as always for the insight, truly. And even more reason to have corrected the post to avoid the usage of those classes.